# Hover on menu and click submenu item with selenium vba

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mousehover, findelement

I have a menu dropdown like this. Using selenium i need to move the menu but can retreive the element by ID, xPath etc.
Cau you help plz

```
<td id="140#200" nowrap="" class="k140" onclick="menuclic(&quot;140&quot;,this,&quot;#200&quot;)" onmousedown="menudown(&quot;140&quot;,this)" onmouseup="menuup(&quot;140&quot;,this)" onmousemove="menumousemove(&quot;140&quot;,this,'#200')" onmouseover="menuover(&quot;140&quot;,this)" onmouseout="menuout(&quot;140&quot;,this)">&nbsp;Suivi&nbsp;des&nbsp;réclamations&nbsp;</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with that problem like this. Of course, it is just an example.

```
//Instantiate Action Class        
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
//Retrieve WebElement 'Music' to perform mouse hover 
WebElement menuOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(text(),'Music')]"));
//Mouse hover menuOption 'Music'
actions.moveToElement(menuOption).perform();
System.out.println("Done Mouse hover on 'Music' from Menu");

//Now Select 'Rock' from sub menu which has got displayed on mouse hover of 'Music'
WebElement subMenuOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(text(),'Rock')]")); 
//Mouse hover menuOption 'Rock'
actions.moveToElement(subMenuOption).perform();
System.out.println("Done Mouse hover on 'Rock' from Menu");
```

The resulting image is :

[image: here].

Comment: The class seems to be dynamic on the page and there is only the ID which is static but not unique. Any advise?